# loop through numbered class and append shortened url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a bitly script to shorten urls and insert the resulits into a span tag.

Using jquery, how would I loop through the following list ids and replace the long url with the shortened one.

```
<ul class="vertical-list list-parent">
    <li id="license_key_0">
      <div class="primary two-quarter unit-link">
          <span>http://localhost:3000/projects/313f7f5586b39cd9bf7a894894564036</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="license_key_1">
    <div class="primary two-quarter unit-link">
         <span>http://localhost:3000/projects/287a990d17b680fe410329cb95af89b9</span>
   </div>
  </li>
<li id="license_key_2">
  <div class="primary two-quarter unit-link">
       <span>http://localhost:3000/projects/ff381cdb94070e1903c5f6fddc31b148</span>
  </div> 
</li>
  </ul>
```

The jquery:

```
(function ($j) {
      function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func) {
        $j.getJSON(
          "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", {
          "format": "json",
          "apiKey": api_key,
          "login": login,
          "longUrl": long_url
        },
        function (response) {
          func(response.data.url);
        });
      }

      var login = "my_login";
      var api_key = "my_api_key";
      var long_url = "m";

      get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function (short_url) {
        console.log(short_url);
      });

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense to do this server-side before the page is rendered.

Comment: can't really do that.  this is an older rails app and i can't upgrade the gems versions to make anything out there usable.  this was the solution we came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.each()` jquery function to iterate over the selector:

```
$('ul .unit-link span').each(
    function(index){
      var long_url = $(this).text();
      get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function (short_url) {
          console.log(short_url);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
    (function ($) {
    function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func) {
        $.getJSON(
            "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", {
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": long_url
        },
        function (response) {
            func(response.data.url);
        });
    }

    var login = "my_login";
    var api_key = "my_api_key";

    $("ul.list-parent li").each(function()
                                {
                                   var long_url = $(this).find("span").text();

                                    get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function (short_url) {
                                                console.log(short_url);
                                              }); 
                                }
                               );


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$j.each($j("li div.primary"), function() {
    var long_url = $j(this).find("span").html();

    get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, 
        function(short_url) { console.log(short_url) }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.ajax` with `dataType: "jsonp"`. And to iterate, use `.each` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/37Zv4/.

```
(function ($j) {
  function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func) {
      $j.ajax({
        url: "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten",
        data: {
          "format": "json",
          "apiKey": api_key,
          "login": login,
          "longUrl": long_url
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
          func(response.data.url);
        }
    });
  }

  var login = "bitlyapioauthdemo";
  var api_key = "R_f6397a37e765574f2e198dba5bb59522";

    $(".unit-link span").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      get_short_url($this.text(), login, api_key, function (short_url) {
        $this.text(short_url);
      });
    });

})(jQuery);
```